# Jest tests of Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

I need to write a Jest test for a function using Promises, which is working perfectly in the browser.

My code is as follows: a JQuery AJAX call is done, which returns a promise; when this promise is resolved, I call another function, which is also using another Promises internally!

So the code of my Jest test is globally like this:

```
function post(url) {
  return $.ajax(url).then((result) => {
    resolve(result);
  });
}

function showAlert(message) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    require('anotherPackage').then(() => {  // require returns a Promise
      anotherPackage.showAlert(message);    // will result in DOM update
    }).then(resolve, reject);
  });
}

function handleResponse(result) {
  const promises = [];
  ...
  promises.push(showAlert(message));
  ...
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

test("Promises test", () => {
  let response = null,
      url = 'http://example.com/result.json';
  return post(url).then([result, status, request] => {
    response = parseResponse(result);
  }).then(() => {
    return handleResponse(response).then(() => {
      return $('.alert').length;
    }).then(value => {
      expect(value).toBe(1);  // doesn't work, value is 0 !!!
    });
  });
});
```

The *handleResponse* function is using AJAX request response, and in this use case, the function is calling another function which is using a promise internally which, when resolved, is creating an alert inside the DOM.

Actually, the test given as example doesn't work, because the *expect* call is done before the inner *handleResponse* promise is "completely resolved"!

So my question is: how can I handle this use case with Jest?

Best regards,

Thierry

Comment: This is integration test that can fail on many levels. It's preferable to not do real requests and to not use real DOM. Test these units separately, one by one. It's not guaranteed that showAlert results in `$('.alert').length === 1` in Jest. But you won't know for sure because there are other units that can fail. Even if it works in a browser, Jest run in Node and it isn't expected to work like a browser, although it can on some conditions.

Comment: *because the expect call is done before the inner handleResponse promise is "completely resolved"* - what did make you think so? The code doesn't suggest that, although promise chains are messy and contain antipatterns, better switch to async..await in tests to have better idea what's going on.

Comment: @EstusFlask, I don't do real requests, I didn't put all the test code but I use a mock for JQuery AJAX function and XMLHTTPRequest which works fine in other contexts. And the different units (like "showAlert") are tested separately but I would like to test the main function, which I can't achieve...
I've used Node debugger with Chrome inspector to check the order into which Promises are resolved, and that's why I think that the "expect" call is done before the previous promise is completely resolved...